# Ejercicio manejo de cadenas (Strings) en C

Tags: c

Quería saber si me pueden ayudar pasándome, si tienen o conocen, problemas de manejo de cadenas. Eh buscado por Internet pero siempre son sobre encriptar, desencriptar cadenas, remplazar caracteres, invertir cadena, contar ocurrencia, etc.
Estaba buscando algo mas interesante.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿qué puede ser más interesante que encriptar una cadena?

Comment: @jachguate descifrarla ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Hackerrank tienen una sección con ejercicios sobre strings muy buena, aunque en inglés https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms/strings

En español puedes revisar www.aceptaelreto.com. https://www.aceptaelreto.com/problems/categories.php/?cat=16

Answer (score 2):

Podrías probar a resolver problemas que no solamente involucren manejo de cadenas sino también algoritmos, como el problema de la subsecuencia común más larga (en inglés Longest Common Substring, o LCS).

No encontré ejercicios en español, pero si también conoces inglés, puedes revisar éste en [Codeforces](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/161/C) o la información [aquí](http://xcodigoinformatico.blogspot.pe/2012/09/subsecuencia-comun-mas-larga-con.html) descrita.